# Need to write out grid 9x9 number text file to a new text file in the same format C++

Tags: c++, arrays, filestream

[This is the input file that my output file needs to be the same as](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qR4kw.png)

[this is the output I currently have (its getting closer)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfza9.png)

The first part of the problem that I have completed is to write a method that takes grid text file of 9x9 numbers into a 2d array and saves each row of the text file into each memory slot, while the other slot of the array holds the column of the numbers in each slot. here's the code to show that:

```
void Grid::LoadGrid(char const * const)
{
    int m_grid[9][9];     
    ifstream fp ("Grid1.txt"); 
    for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) 
    {
        for(int y =0; y < 9; y++) 
        {
            fp >> m_grid[x][y]; 
        }
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) 
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++)
        {
            cout << m_grid[x][y] << " "; 
        }
        cout << endl;

        return;
        fp.close(); 
    }       
}
```

That works perfectly. second problem is to now take that array and output it into a new text file what I called "GridOut.txt" heres the code for that:

```
     void Grid::SaveGrid(char const * const)
{
    int m_grid[9][9];
    ifstream fp("Grid1.txt");
    ofstream fout("GridOut.txt");

    for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++)
        {
            fp >> m_grid[x][y];
            fout << m_grid[x][y];
        }
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++)
        {

         fout << m_grid[x][y] << " ";

        }
        fout << endl;


    }
```

}

This is creating a new file and putting the values in but it's not in the 9x9 grid format as it is meant to be.

Sorry for my bad English and hope it's explained well enough for people to understand.

Comment: Do you just want to rename the file then ?

Comment: Welcome on SO! Couple of advices which will increase probability of getting answers. Please do not put lines like: ''''''''''' and try to start sentences with capital letter. You will show respect to readers that you've put some effort to prepare question and they will more likely want to put their effor to help you. I would also add expected and actual output samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fout << m_grid[x][y] << endl;
```

This puts a newline after every number. You should replace that with a space:

```
fout << m_grid[x][y] << " ";
```

And instead of `cout << endl` do `fout << endl`.

This is the result:

```
void Grid::SaveGrid(char const* const) {
  int m_grid[9][9];
  ifstream fp("Grid1.txt");
  ofstream fout("GridOut.txt");

  for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++) {
      fp >> m_grid[x][y];
    }
  }

  for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++) {
      fout << m_grid[x][y] << " ";
    }
    fout << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the lesson my friend I have used that now, however, unfortunately, this doesn't solve the problem completely. I have included some images of the top of what I need it to look like vs what it output's

Comment: @LittleCoderBoy Get rid of the `return;` and `file.close()` as well.

Comment: @LittleCoderBoy Please look at the update to my answer.

Comment: Thank you! these edits are now inputting it in a 9x9 grid form now but strangely in a weird order I will update my question and outputs so you can see

Comment: Please Look at the new edits and let me know what you think!

Comment: @LittleCoderBoy That first line of output (with the bunched up numbers) is not coming from this function.

Comment: is that coming from the LoadGrid Method then?

Comment: @LittleCoderBoy It could be. Try to find out.